# Shapes, Drawable"Shapename", Shape Inheritance and Interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract, implements

This is my last exercise in my headfirst book but when i run the application the shape is not being drawn, I'm pretty stumped cause there are no errors.

```
public class ShapesDriver extends Frame{ //You said Frame in the Tutorial4 Document
    private ArrayList<Drawable> drawable;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ShapesDriver gui = new ShapesDriver();

        gui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });    
    }

    public ShapesDriver(){
        super("Shapes");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        show();
    }

    public void Paint (Graphics g){
        DrawableRectangle rect1 = new DrawableRectangle(150, 100);
        drawable.add(rect1);
        for(int i = 0; i < drawable.size(); i++){
            drawable.get(i).draw(g);
        }        
    }
}
```

DrawableRectangle Class

```
public class DrawableRectangle extends Rectangle implements Drawable{
    private int x, y;
    public DrawableRectangle(int height, int width){
        super(height, width);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColour(Color c) {
        this.setColour(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Rectangle Class

```
public abstract class Rectangle implements Shape {
    public int height, width;

    Rectangle(int Height, int Width){
        this.height = Height;
        this.width = Width;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() { return width * height; }
}
```

Shape Class

```
public interface Shape {
    public double area();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with, Java is case sensitive, so `public void Paint (Graphics g){` is never going to be called by Java, as the method name is `paint`

Then lets move onto, you should rarely, if ever, extend a top level container like `JFrame` and especially override the `paint` method. `paint` does a lot of really important work and you should always call `super.paint`

Instead, you should extend from something `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method instead (remembering to call `super.paintComponwnt`)

And then I'd include Rohit's suggestions.

You might like to have a read through

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)